# How to send a .google.protobuf.BytesValue via grpcurl?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpcurl

i am planning to call following message using grpcurl.
How to send a .google.protobuf.BytesValue via grpcurl?

```
message TestRequest {
  .google.protobuf.BytesValue TestJson = 1;
  string Temp = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`BytesValues`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.BytesValue) is a message (wrapper) for `bytes`.

Try Base64 encoding the `bytes` field and passing it that way.

Protobuf's [JSON encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) of bytes is a Base64 string.